# How can I get a JUNG edge length?

Tags: edges, jung

How do I get an edge length from a graph constructed in JUNG? In pixels would be nice, but if it's more complicated, then please explain.

Comment: It's been a while since I last used Jung. As I recall edges could be straight, quadratic, cubic... so the edge between two nodes could have different lengths, depending on your View or Renderer (or what it was called). So is it really about edge length, or just the distance between the nodes?

Comment: You are correct, my edges are straight which made me think I needed their length but what I actually need is the distance between linked nodes. The reason I need this information is to add weights to my links for a weighted shortest path algorithm. Any idea how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can get the distance in Layout coordinates by getting the position for each vertex in the Layout and then doing the obvious math.

Second, I don't understand why you want the link weight to be a function of how the layout placed the vertices.  This seems kind of arbitrary.  Usually, if anything, it's the other way around (edge weight determines vertex placement in Layout).

Finally, assuming you're using Dijkstra{Distance,ShortestPath}, you can provide any kind of edge weights that you like; take a look at the Javadoc for how to do this.

What's the underlying problem you're trying to solve?